# sed pipe not returning expected exit code

Tags: bash, sed

Why does the following command not return a non-zero exit code ?

```
badcommand | sed 'q1' ; echo $?
```

Screenshot:

[image]

### Update:

Seems to work if I redirect all output to stdout:

```
badcommand 2>&1 | sed 'q1' ; echo $?
```

Comment: I would expect something like: `sed: 1: "q1": extra characters at the end of q command`.  You must be using a non-standard `sed`.

Comment: My guess is that since `sed` never sees any input, it never executes the command `q1`.

Comment: Agree with William. the sed never gets a record to perform its program on, so it never executes the `q`uit at all, so can't do so with the specified return code. `echo | sed 'q1' ; echo $?` does exactly what it should, though, and exits with a 1.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text in place of text, it makes it hard to search for. That said, is this specific to sed?

Answer (score 4):

`sed` will execute the command `q1` on the first line of input that it sees.  (For versions of `sed` in which `q1` is not a syntax error.)  Since `badcommand` never generates any output, `sed` doesn't see any input, so it does not execute that command.

You can confirm this behavior with:

```
$ { printf 'foo\nbar\n'; badcommand; } | sed q1 ; echo $?
-bash: badcommand: command not found
foo
1
```

Nearly anything you can do with `sed` you can also do easily with `awk`, so you might consider something like:

```
$ badcommand | awk 'END{ exit NR == 0 }'; echo $?
```

Note that this is a bit convoluted. If there is no input, then NR will be 0 in the END block, so exit will return a non-zero value which is boolean true.  This is a never ending source of confusion.  (For me, at least!)

Comment: This gave me the idea to pipe `badcommand`'s output to stderr. Apparently `sed` only reads from stdout.

Comment: `sed will execute the command q1 on each line of input` I doubt that. As far as I know, `sed` will immediately quit with the optional exit status, even if there are other pending files, let alone the current file being processed. Edit: Your sample command shows only `foo` and not `bar` since `sed q` will exit on the very first line... perhaps I'm misunderstanding your description?

Comment: @Sundeep, perhaps I should write "sed will execute the command `q1` on each line of input that it sees until it exits".  As soon as it executes the command once, it exits and does not see any more lines of input.

Comment: That's clearer now, but I think I'm getting thrown off with `on each line of input` since `sed q1` is never going to see 2nd line (or can it in some case that I don't know?).

Answer (score 2):

It's because the last command executed is sed and not badcommand, so the exit status is the exit code of the sed, not badcommand.
If you want the exit code of badcommand you have to do this:

```
  echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```